# Android Studio + Database - Multiple check data to insert data if not exists

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm having a problem with my code. I don't know how to check multiple columns in the database to insert different data on every not existing data.

## **For example**:

### *1st input*

### Name: Raymond Jay Berin

### Event: INTRAMURALS

### FACILITATOR: CSG

### *2nd input*

### Name: Raymond Jay Berin

### Event: LOVE SYMPOSIUM

### FACILITATOR: DSSC

the thing here is that. Raymond Jay Berin already existed in the database, but I want Raymond Jay Berin will be inserted into a different event...

also, I already tried to create multiple tables but my project crashes when I click the attendance button to add data.

### Code for **DatabaseHelper.class**:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "attendance.sqlite";

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "attendance";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "FULLNAME";
public static final String COL_EVENT_2 = "EVENT_NAME";
public static final String COL_EVENT_3 = "FACILITATOR_NAME";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //ATTENDANCE
db.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "FULLNAME TEXT NOT NULL, EVENT_NAME TEXT NOT NULL, FACILITATOR_NAME TEXT NOT NULL)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //ATTENDANCE
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME );

    //recreate
    onCreate(db);
}

//ATTENDANCE
public boolean insertData (String fullname, String event, String facilitator){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,fullname);
    contentValues.put(COL_EVENT_2,event);
    contentValues.put(COL_EVENT_3,facilitator);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
        else
            return true;
}
public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}

public boolean checkIfRecordExist(String nameOfTable,String columnName,String columnValue) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+columnName+" FROM "+nameOfTable+" WHERE "+columnName+"='"+columnValue+"'",null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            db.close();
            Log.d("Record Already Exists", "Table is:" + nameOfTable + " ColumnName:" + columnName);
            return true;//record Exists

        }
        Log.d("New Record  ", "Table is:" + nameOfTable + " ColumnName:" + columnName + " Column Value:" + columnValue);
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception errorException) {
        Log.d("Exception occured", "Exception occured " + errorException);
        db.close();
    }
    return false;



} }
```

### Code for the Attendance.java class

```
public class Attendance extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText fname , eventname, faciname;
Button attendance;
Button view;
Switch lock;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    fname = findViewById(R.id.txtFullname);
    eventname = findViewById(R.id.eventname);
    faciname = findViewById(R.id.faciname);
    attendance = findViewById(R.id.btnatt);
    view = findViewById(R.id.btnview);
    lock = findViewById(R.id.switchLock);
    viewAll();
    AddData();
    lock.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (lock.isChecked()){
        eventname.setEnabled(false);
        faciname.setEnabled(false);
    }else{
        eventname.setEnabled(true);
        faciname.setEnabled(true);
    }

}


public void viewAll() {
    view.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
                    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                        // show message
                        showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
                        return;
                    }

                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    while (res.moveToNext()) {
                        buffer.append("ID :" + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                        buffer.append("NAME :" + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                        buffer.append("EVENT :" + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                        buffer.append("FACILITATOR :" + res.getString(3) + "\n"+"\n");
                    }

                    // Show all data
                    showMessage("ATTENDANCE LIST", buffer.toString());
                }
            }
    );
}

public void showMessage(String title, String Message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}

public void AddData() {
    attendance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String valInput = fname.getText().toString();
            final String valInput1 = eventname.getText().toString();
            final String valInput2 = faciname.getText().toString();
            boolean valid = true;

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(valInput)) {
                fname.setError("This Item must not be empty!");
                valid = false;
                }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(valInput1)) {
                eventname.setError("This Item must not be empty!");
                valid = false;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(valInput2)) {
                faciname.setError("This Item must not be empty!");
                valid = false;
            }
                if (valid) {
                    boolean isExist = myDb.checkIfRecordExist(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COL_1, fname.getText().toString());
                    if (!isExist) {
                        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(fname.getText().toString(), eventname.getText().toString(), faciname.getText().toString());
                            if (isInserted) {
                                Toast.makeText(Attendance.this, "Attendance Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                fname.setText(null);
                            } else if (isInserted == false) {
                                Toast.makeText(Attendance.this, "Failed to Attendance", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                    }else if (isExist == true){
                        Toast.makeText(Attendance.this, "Failed to Attendance "+fname+" Already Existed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                    }
                    }); }


public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //Handle the back button
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //Ask the user if they want to quit
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle(R.string.Logout)
                .setMessage(R.string.really_logout)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        //Stop the activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Attendance.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Attendance.this.finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
                .show();

        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}}
```

Comment: The person `Raymond Berin` has an id, right? And it stays in a table where only Persons are stored. Associate that id with different rows on the Events table. Then query the Events table where the id is that of `Raymond Berin`.

Comment: Yes, `Raymond` has an ID. I still don't get the point, I'm still confused. beginner's problems. anyways, thanks @Kling Klang, for the comment

Comment: Then you probably still have to understand how related tables work. It's just as easy as learning the `INNER JOIN` concept in queries.

Answer (score 0):

change `checkIfRecordExist` method like this

```
public boolean checkIfRecordExist(String nameOfTable,String columnName1,String columnValue1,String columnName2,String columnValue2) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+nameOfTable+" WHERE "+columnName1+"='"+columnValue1+"' and "+ columnName2 +"='"+columnValue2+"'",null);
.......................
```

change below line like this

```
boolean isExist = myDb.checkIfRecordExist(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COL_1, fname.getText().toString(),DatabaseHelper.COL_2, eventname.getText().toString())
```

Comment: Thanks, @Lucefer, I will try this one.

Comment: sorry I mistakenly added double quotes to column name in that query, now i changed it to corrrect one. please try it again using this query

Comment: Thank you, I will try it now. sorry for the delayed reply I went to sleep.